# What would be the Java regex for this pattern?

Tags: java, regex

My strings look like:

> some space delimited fixed text: space delimited text: space delimited text...

Example string:

```
"Mary had a little lamb: it says: baah..."
```

Here, `"Mary had a little lamb: "` string is a constant. It will always be followed by a string which contains alpha numeric characters, colon and space followed by ellipsis. `"it says: baah"` may change. ... will always be there.

I have this so far as regex:

```
"Mary had a little lamb: ^[a-zA-Z:]\\.\\.\\."
```

but this doesn't work.

I don't know how to incorporate the space after colon in `"it says: baah"`. How do I have to write a regular expression that recognizes these strings?

Comment: `\s` is the white space character, is your goal to get the value of `baba` variable? What are you trying to achieve using Regex?

Comment: I want to match all strings that follow the pattern: "Mary had a little lamb: <chars>: <chars>..."

Comment: Why use a regex? You can just do str.startWith("Mary had a little lamb:") && st.endsWith("...") to see if the string matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use the beginning operator inside of your regex and your string may include other characters than letters. Try:

```
"Mary had a little lamb: .*?\\.\\.\\."
```

The question mark is for non greedy / shortest possible matches. You may remove it to receive longest possible matches.

This more specific pattern requires a colon and restricts the possible characters:

```
"Mary had a little lamb: [^:]*:[ A-Za-z]*\\.\\.\\."
```

The `[^:]*` matches any string that doesn't contain a colon.

For testing in Java (Bean Shell):

```
p = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("Mary had a little lamb: [^:]*:[ A-Za-z]*\\.\\.\\.");
m = p.matcher("Mary had a little lamb: it says: baah...");
print(m.matches());
```

Comment: There will be colon and space too.

Comment: Yes, right. My regex matches all characters. I will add a more specific regex.

Comment: How are you testing the regex?

Comment: :) In the Python interpreter. I've modified the variant for the evil apostrophe in your string. ;)

Comment: Tweaked my example, not expecting an apostrophe.

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot. Can you please explain [^:]*: part of the regex. Also, I thought that space has to be treated by a special character in Java, but apparently, no.